# sending email in c#

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, credentials

I want to send email in c#.I implement all code but receiving error .........it
 point  out rror on smtp.port=465;I also use code for specifying host.but i am 
  not understanding why i am getting this type of error???????

**.aspx code**

```
        public void click(object sender, EventArgs sd)
            {


                try
                {



                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new   
   System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    //smessage.To.Add(TextBox1.Text);
                    message.To.Add(System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(TextBox1.Text));
                    message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
                    message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(TextBox2.Text);
                    message.Body = "This is the message body";
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new        
               System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.yahoo.mail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 465;

                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception gf)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: Honestly, tell me if you tried to search for this answer on StackOverflow?

Comment: What is the error?  Here's a hint... You are catching any and all exceptions and promptly _ignoring_ them in your code.  If you want to figure out what's wrong, stop ignoring the exceptions.  Exceptions tend to contain very useful information about what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't supplied any credentials to the server.  How does Yahoo know who you are?

Also you have defined the host in the constructor (not the cause of your error, however just thought I would point it out) `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");` and then redefined it as `smtp.yahoo.mail.com`

There is an article you can use to help you connect to Yahoo Mail via C# found here:

http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=3